# Logging from VBA run Shell not working

Tags: vba, shell, logging

I have this Sub in VBA to run a Python code from cmd and store the process in a log. However, the code runs but the log is not stored at all. Any suggestions?

```
Sub GeneraKPIS()

ret_val = Shell("""C:\Python27\python.exe"" ""C:\Users\gabriem\PycharmProjects\BigPromos\query_info.py"" >> ""C:\Users\gabriem\PycharmProjects\BigPromos\log.txt""")

End Sub
```

Best regards!

Comment: Show the `query_info.py` code?

Comment: Does it run ok, when you try it from the terminal?

Comment: Hi @Vityata. Yes!! It works from the cmd but not from VBA. The log.txt has been created. Do you know why?

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
ret_val = Shell("""C:\Python27\python.exe"" ""C:\Users\gabriem\PycharmProjects\BigPromos\query_info.py >> C:\Users\gabriem\PycharmProjects\BigPromos\log.txt""")
```

And see what happens. I assume that `Shell` does not like this part - `"" >> ""`. If it does not work, play a bit with the `"` sign, e.g. try like this:

```
"""C:\Python27\python.exe"" ""C:\Users\gabriem\PycharmProjects\BigPromos\query_info.py""" & " >> " & """C:\Users\gabriem\PycharmProjects\BigPromos\log.txt"""
```

The idea is to make exactly the string, that would work in the terminal also. To see the string, use the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)in VBA and the `?` sign before the string.

E.g.:

```
?"""Some\python.exe"" ""BigPromos\query_info.py""" & " >> " & """BigPromos\log.txt"""
```

would give:

```
"Some\python.exe" "BigPromos\query_info.py" >> "BigPromos\log.txt"
```

Comment: Can you write **exactly** the command that you write on the terminal?

Comment: I typed ?"""C:\Python27\python.exe"" ""C:\Users\gabriem\PycharmProjects\BigPromos\query_info.py""" & " >> " & """C:\Users\gabriem\PycharmProjects\BigPromos\log.txt"""

Comment: This is definitely not what you have written in the terminal, when you said that the program works, @GabrielaMartinez

Comment: It worked in the VBA cmd, but I typed the result in the VBA Macro and it fails. What am I supposed to do with the result of this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, simply write `"""Some\python.exe"" ""BigPromos\query_info.py""" & " >> " & """BigPromos\log.txt"""` in the "macro" (without the `?`).